# resolve function from parent node to child node angularjs ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having two roles. Administrator and Moderator.

Administrator is allowed for roles view and Moderator is  not.

I pass the resolve parameter to adminCtrl **(parent)** so that i dont get error if the moderator wants to access other admin views.

All i want is if administrator is using,then the roles should get updated from undefined to some value. But its still remaining undefined.

Is the only solution to use seperate controller for it?

**App.js**

```
 .state('menu.adminusers', {
                        url: "/adminusers",
                        controller:'adminusersCtrl',
                        templateUrl: "views/adminusers/adminusers.tpl.html",
                        resolve:{roles:function(){return undefined}},
                        permissions:{allow : ['administrator','moderator']}
                        }
              )
        .state('menu.adminusers.roles', {
                        url: "/adminusers/adminroles",
                        templateUrl: "views/adminusers/roles.tpl.html",
                        resolve:{roles:function(){return "asdf"}},
                        permissions:{allow : ['administrator']}
                        }
              )
```

**Controller**

```
adminpanel.controller('adminusersCtrl',function($scope,apiService,$state,roles){

    console.log(roles);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. I just added the controller again and it solved the problem

```
  .state('menu.adminusers.roles', {
                                url: "/adminusers/adminroles",
                                templateUrl: "views/adminusers/roles.tpl.html",
                                controller:'adminusersCtrl', //added this controller and it solved my problem.
                                resolve : { roles : function(){return "asdf"}},
                                permissions:{allow : ['administrator']}
                                }
                      )
```